# Retrieving a list of Entities with search criteria on its Many to one relation field

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities - MembershipPlan and PurchaseRecord. PurchaseRecord to MembershipPlan is a **Unidirectional** **Many-to-one** relationship, modeled like this :

```
@Entity
public class MembershipPlan {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  ... other fields
}

@Entity
public class PurchaseRecord {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id; 

  private Long userid; 
    
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "planid", referencedColumnName = "id") 
  MembershipPlan plan;

  ... other fields  
}
```

I want to retrieve all PurchaseRecords for a given userid and a given MembershipPlan id.

In SQL, I would just do this:

```
select * from purchase_record pr where pr.userid=? and pr.planid=?
```

But I am not able to figure out how to do it using Spring's CrudRepository. I tried the following but this is not working.

```
public interface PurchaseRecordRepo extends CrudRepository<PurchaseRecord , Long> {
        
    @Query(value = "SELECT pr FROM PurchaseRecord pr join fetch p.plan WHERE pr.userid = :userid and pr.plan :plan")
    public List<PurchaseRecord> getPRsByUseridPlanId(@Param("userid") Long userid, @Param("plan") MembershipPlan plan);
    
}
```

The error says:

```
unexpected token: : near line 1, column 111 [SELECT pr FROM PurchaseRecord pr join fetch p.plan WHERE pr.userid = :userid and pr.plan :plan ]
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I don't need @Query at all in this case. The following one liner did the job:

```
public List<PurchaseRecord> getUnusedByUseridAndPlan_Id(@Param("userid") Long userid, @Param("id") Integer id);
```

Since PurchaseRecord has a field named **plan** of type MembershipPlan, which, in turn, has a field named **id**, the CrudRepository automatically generates the right query by inspecting the method name if it contains "**Plan_Id**"!